# Как преобразовать тип real к byte?

Tags: pascal

Нельзя преобразовать тип real к byte. Решаю этот пример в паскале [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
Program SUMMA;
var K1, K2, i, Z: byte;
BEGIN
write('vvedite K1= ');
readln(K1);
write('vvedite K2= ');
readln(K2);
Z:=0;
For i:=1 to K1 do
Z:= Z + sqr(i)/2;
writeln('SUMMA= ',Z:5);
readln;
END.
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: @entithat да я пробывал но после этого у меня выдае ошибку Ожидался порядковый тип и подсвечиват эту строку  For i:=1 to K1 do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как `k1, k2` - **целые** числа *(видно по условию задания)*, то для них стоит использовать тип `byte`.
А для `z` стоит использовать тип `real`.

Почему в **z** получается вещественный тип? В формуле есть деление числа на 2, а число может быть нечётным.

A `i` - целый тип, ведь цикл не может повторяться допустим полтора раза, поэтому для него используем **целочиселнный** тип `byte`.

```
program sum;
var 
    k1, k2, i: byte;
    z:real;
begin
    write('vvedite k1= ');
    readln(k1);
    write('vvedite k2= ');
    readln(k2);
    z:=0;
    for i:=1 to k1 do
        z:= z + sqr(i)/2;
        writeln('Sum = ', z:5);
    readln;
end.
```